# Forcing Eloquent models to re resolve database connection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there any way to force Eloquent models to re resolve the connection they were instantiated with?

Right now I have a method that changes the database connection in a loop :

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

   Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $key . '_' . $database);

   $productRepo = new ProductRepository();    

   $products = $productRepo->all();

}
```

Inside the product repository, i'm calling the Eloquent methods all() to get all the products in the database.

What i discover was that the connection was changed to the first value in the array but it does not change on further executions of the loop.

Is there anything I can do to force Eloquent to resolve the connection parameters at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each database is really a separate connection, so I would setup all the connections to the database in the `config/database.php` file, and then you can use the `setConnection()` method on the model to switch between them.

database.php:

```
return [
    'default' => 'mysql-key1',
    'connections' => [
        'mysql-key1' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'database'  => 'key1_dbname,
            // etc
        ],
        'mysql-key2' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'database'  => 'key2_dbname',
            // etc
        ]
    ]
];
```

ProductRepository.php:

```
public function setConnection($name) {
    // assumes $this->product is your Product model
    $this->product->setConnection($name);
}
```

Code:

```
$productRepo = new ProductRepository();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
   $productRepo->setConnection($key . '_' . $database);
   $products = $productRepo->all();
}
```

### Edit

*additional information based on comments*

Laravel is only going to instantiate a connection to the database the first time it is needed. Once the connection has been created, it is going to reuse it. It would be a huge performance issue if you had to reconnect to the database for every single query.

That being said, if you really want to do this the way you originally designed it, all you would need to do is call the `DB::reconnect()` method after updating the config.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $key . '_' . $database);
    DB::reconnect();

    $productRepo = new ProductRepository();
    $products = $productRepo->all();
}
```

However, I would strongly urge you to consider the originally described option so that you're not making a ton of unnecessary connections.

Comment: thanks! this could work. however I still do not understand why the model would still refer to the first connection even though it was changed dynamically. hope someone can explain !

Comment: @yulun I have added some information to the answer based on your comment.

Comment: hey @patricus, sorry to revisit the question but do you know if the method create() works differently from the query methods? because even after using setConnection() on the model, the create() method still points to the previous database.

Comment: @yulun The problem is that `setConnection()` works on an instance of a class, but the `create()` method is a static method on the class itself. All the `create()` method does is instantiate a new instance with the given attributes, and call `save()`. So, instead of using `create()`, you'll just need to do this manually: `$productRepo = new ProductRepository($attributes); $productRepo->setConnection($key . '_' . $database); $productRepo->save();` You could also override the `create()` method on the ProductRepository class to accept a connection to do this, as well.

Comment: just in case others are looking at the same problem as well .. you can refer to a better explained answer by @patricus here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069101/multi-tenancy-in-laravel-eloquent-orm

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did not have a database config for each of my databases, since they are created dynamically.  I used the following approach, just changing the table name to include the database name as well (This works for MySQL):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
   $productRepo = new ProductRepository();  
   $productRepo->setTable($key . '_' . $database);  
   $products = $productRepo->all();
}
```