# Multi tenancy in Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

This is sort of a follow up question from

[Forcing Eloquent models to re resolve database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870084/forcing-eloquent-models-to-re-resolve-database-connection/28871610)

With multiple database connections :

```
return [
    'default' => 'mysql-key1',
    'connections' => [
        'mysql-key1' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'database'  => 'key1_dbname,
            // etc
        ],
        'mysql-key2' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'database'  => 'key2_dbname',
            // etc
        ]
    ]
];
```

I have a product repository which uses the Model setConnection to change the connection attribute :

```
public function setConnection($name) {
    // assumes $this->product is your Product model
    $this->product->setConnection($name);
}
```

However, i found out that it only worked on query methods and not methods like Model::create ::

```
$productRepo = new ProductRepository();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
   $productRepo->setConnection($key . '_' . $database);
   // this works
   $products = $productRepo->all();
   // this doesn't work and will use the old connection 
   $product = $productRepo->create($data); 
}
```

Seems that the ::create method does not resolve the connection once the instance has been created. Anyone knows a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `setConnection()` works on an instance of a class, but the `create()` method is a static method on the class itself. In your repository, `$this->product` is an instance of the Product class. Using `setConnection()` on this instance before doing queries will work fine, but you'll need to do a little more manual work if you want to use separate connections on the static methods (such as `create()`).

All the `create()` method does is instantiate a new instance with the given attributes and then call `save()`. So, instead of calling `create()` on the Product model, you'll just need to do this manually:

```
class ProductRepository {
    public function create(array $attributes, $connection = null) {
        $product = $this->product->newInstance($attributes);
        $product->setConnection($connection ?: $this->product->getConnectionName());
        $product->save();
        return $product;
    }
}
```

You could also override the static `create()` method on the Product model to accept a connection, as well.

```
class Product extends Model {
    public static function create(array $attributes, $connection = null) {
        $model = new static($attributes);
        $model->setConnection($connection ?: $this->connection);
        $model->save();
        return $model;
    }
}

class ProductRepository {
    public function create(array $attributes, $connection = null) {
        $connection = $connection ?: $this->product->getConnectionName()
        return $this->product->create($attributes, $connection);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks again @patricus for your answers. in your opinion though, do you think the original source code should attempt to resolve the connection before calling save() in the create method?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to utilize Model Events & Observers to manipulate the connection being used, documentation is available here:

- http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events
- http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-observers

You could create a single DatabaseModelObserver (As below) that you could attached to each of the relevant models that will set the connection before saving and reset it after saving as below:

```
class DatabaseModelObserver {

    protected $databases = [
        'default' => 'mysql-key1',
        'products' => 'mysql-key2'
    ];

    protected $connection;

    public function __construct(Connection $connection)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public function saving($model)
    {
        $this->connection->reconnect($this->databases['products']);
    }

    public function saved($model)
    {
        $this->connection->reconnect($this->databases['default']);
    }
}
```

You would then attach the observer to the relevant models via a Service Provider, utilizing the boot method as detailed below:

```
class ModelServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        ProductModel::observe(
            $this->app->make('DatabaseModelObserver')
        );
    }
}
```

You could attach this same Observer to as many models as required, you just need to add them to the boot method, eg:

```
public function boot()
{
    ProductModel::observe(
        $this->app->make('DatabaseModelObserver')
    );
    CategoryModel::observe(
        $this->app->make('DatabaseModelObserver')
    );
    StoreModel::observe(
        $this->app->make('DatabaseModelObserver')
    );
}
```

This should work with all your existing repositories, providing your repositories use Eloquent under the hood, which I'm assuming them do.

The code above is untested, and the specifics surrounding the connection class injected into the observer may be off, but are based on the documentation on the DB Facade - Can't post any more links :(

EDIT

Having looked into patricus answer in a little more detail, using a model event should solve his issue with the static nature of the create method.

The instance of the Model being saved is passed to each model event, in my example above as `$model` therefore there should be no issues doing the below in your model observer instead:

```
public function saving($model)
{
    $model->setConnection($this->databases['products']);
}

public function saved($model)
{
    $model->setConnection($this->databases['default']);
}
```

This should be a much more efficient solution.